# Tensorflow Object Detection API - CheckpointReader ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have follow this [instruction](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and this [doc](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#preparing-the-workspace).
So I have :

- tensorflow-gpu==2.3.1
- object_detection correcly install.
- A working dir that respect the documentation the API.

But when I try to run : model_main_tf2.py

I get the error :

```
  File "defects_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "defects_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 110, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 566, in train_loop
    unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 339, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    if not is_object_based_checkpoint(checkpoint_path):
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 302, in is_object_based_checkpoint
    var_names = [var[0] for var in tf.train.list_variables(checkpoint_path)]
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_utils.py", line 98, in list_variables
    reader = load_checkpoint(ckpt_dir_or_file)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpoint_utils.py", line 67, in load_checkpoint
    return py_checkpoint_reader.NewCheckpointReader(filename)
  File "G:\Documents\Florian\Programmation\DIADES_Defects_Detection\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 96, in NewCheckpointReader
    return CheckpointReader(a)
ValueError
```

They are no text after ValueError.

I read and reread my pipeline.config. It seems good.
And I check on internet. I don't find the solution.
Did you have any advice or solution for this problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the problem.
I forget a 's' in the path of pipeline.congif for "fine_tune_checkpoint"

So we will know that this error means you make a mistake in the path of your checkpoint.